# PKPDsim new_ode_model () function acceptable symbolic variables

Tags: c++, r, ode

Does the new_ode_model()function from the PKPDsim package support K12, K21, K31 etc as a symbolic variable or do you have to manually input Q/V, Q/V2 etc?

```
model = new_ode_model(code = "
                      dAdt[1] = -KA * A[1]
                      dAdt[2] = +KA * A[1] -(CL/V) * A[2] -K12* A[2] + K21 * A[3]
                      dAdt[3] = -K21* A[3] +K12* A[2]", 
                      obs = list(cmt = 2, scale = "V"))
```